# macbook pro battery looks fine , but computer won't work on it and its not charging?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

My macbook battery is 94% charge , condition is normal and cycle count is 30 , it used to work fine a couple of days ago . now computer won't boot on if not connected to power and if I disconnect power it shuts down .

how do I make sure that battery is or is not dead ??

#### Edit1:

also when the charger and the battery is connected its not stable and reboots.

if the battery is disconnected , it doesn't reboot ( but I think something is up with the performance ) .

#### Edit 2:

its a macbook pro 2011 [specs](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.0-15-early-2011-unibody-thunderbolt-specs.html) with 16G of ram.

I also did a hardware diagnostic without the battery and no problems were found.

Comment: What is the model/release date of your MacBook? Is it one of the old white ones or the new 2015+ release?

Comment: @www139 please review edit 2

Comment: Is the battery the original that shipped with the computer? If so, I would guess the battery is bad. I've seen this before. Sometimes, as a battery fails, it returns an inaccurate cycle count and charge level. My guess is, most likely, your battery has failed. Most certain possible if the battery is the original.

Comment: Battery went bad . It was fake I think

Comment: that's terrible but believable. Also, there are methods of properly initializing the battery. Some require draining to nearly 0% on the first cycle and others function best by charging to 100% on the first cycle. Good luck.

Comment: there is a particular listing on eBay where I purchase batteries for my 13" MacBook pros in the past. I can give you a link if you're looking for a recommended battery for a 13" MacBook pro of the 2011 vintage.

Comment: I do for 15" Macbook Pro 2011

Comment: oh, I don't have recommendations for 15" since I've never owned one. I recommend contacting the seller of your previous battery or purchasing a battery with a good warranty. If you buy on eBay, look for a listing with a warranty because it is less likely to be fake. File a case with eBay if necessary. I have only bought off eBay myself as a minor. I don't have cc to buy off Amazon.